# Geodjango: PointField and GEOSGeometry

Tags: django, geometry, point, geodjango

If I can do this:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(1 5)')
>>> print point
POINT (1.0000000000000000 5.0000000000000000)
```

Why can I not do this:

```
>>> lat = 1
>>> lon = 5
>>> point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(lat lon)')

GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Expected number but encountered word: 'lat'
GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKTReader_read_r".
```

How can I use a variable to create a GEOSGeometry object?

Comment: LAT and LONG appear backwards according to gis stackexchange post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/does-y-mean-latitude-and-x-mean-longitude-in-every-gis-software

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can surely do that, but with a slight modification

```
point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' % (lon, lat))
```

OR

```
point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%d %d)' % (lon, lat))
```

When you do

```
`'POINT(lat lon)'`
```

you are *not* replacing the local variables `lat` and `lon` with their appropriate local variable values, and they are being evaluated literally. So, you would need to use substitution.

EDIT: Changed order of `(lat, lon)` to `(lon, lat)` to match the order `GEOSGeometry` is expecting. Although not explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/), it is evident from their examples.

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26472089/1405577 the POINT should be POINT(longitude, latitude). Please correct this comment.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is incorrect.  Points take the form of "POINT(longitude latitude)".  You've reversed them.

Comment: It took me some time to figure this out. I guess this should be mentioned in the documents.